# Makefile error: missing separator, compiling with SDL and OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, gcc, makefile, sdl

I'm using [this generic makefile](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gcmakefile/).

with this custom options:

```
# The pre-processor options used by the cpp (man cpp for more).
CPPFLAGS  = -Wall -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Headers

# The options used in linking as well as in any direct use of ld.
LDFLAGS   = -framework SDL -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL

# The executable file name.
# If not specified, current directory name or `a.out' will be used.
PROGRAM   = app

# The source file types (headers excluded).
# .c indicates C source files, and others C++ ones.
SRCEXTS = .c .C .cc .cpp .CPP .c++ .cxx .cp .m

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJS) $(PROGRAM) $(PROGRAM)
```

instead of:

```
# The pre-processor options used by the cpp (man cpp for more).
CPPFLAGS  = -Wall

# The options used in linking as well as in any direct use of ld.
LDFLAGS   = 

# The executable file name.
# If not specified, current directory name or `a.out' will be used.
PROGRAM   = 

# The source file types (headers excluded).
# .c indicates C source files, and others C++ ones.
SRCEXTS = .c .C .cc .cpp .CPP .c++ .cxx .cp

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJS) $(PROGRAM) $(PROGRAM).exe
```

[Here](http://pastebin.com/fqXxDesJ) you can find complete version of the makefile I'm running.

I'm using Mac OS X 10.6.8 with gcc 4.2.1 and trying to compile a `main.cpp` with `SDLMain.m` and `SDLMain.h` using SDL and OpenGL.

The error that pops up is:

> main.d:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.

and the file main.d (generated by the makefile) is this:

```
-n ./
main.o: main.cpp
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Are you exhibiting the whole file here? Because I don't see an `include` line but it is complaining about the content of a separate file (`main.d`). *// Reading the error message: it's what you do.*

Comment: @dmckee [This](http://pastebin.com/fqXxDesJ) is the complete paste of that file. (Notice also the first line of my question).

Comment: *"(Notice also the first line of my question)"* I don't read code off site: your question should stand on it's own. I especially don't read code off site if it is going to take several clicks to even see it. You have a problem with the existing dependency files (the `.d`s). Clear them out and see if it recurs.

Comment: @dmckee, it recurs. Tried deleting all `.d` files and run `make` and it still does create them again. [The link](http://pastebin.com/fqXxDesJ) I posted you in the comment is one click away, could you please take a look at it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced `echo -n` with `printf` and it solved the problem:

```
# Rules for creating dependency files (.d).
#------------------------------------------

%.d:%.c
    @printf $(dir $<) > $@
    @$(DEPEND.d) $< >> $@

%.d:%.C
    @printf $(dir $<) > $@
    @$(DEPEND.d) $< >> $@

%.d:%.cc
    @printf $(dir $<) > $@
    @$(DEPEND.d) $< >> $@

%.d:%.cpp
    @printf $(dir $<) > $@
    @$(DEPEND.d) $< >> $@

%.d:%.CPP
    @printf $(dir $<) > $@
    @$(DEPEND.d) $< >> $@

%.d:%.c++
    @printf $(dir $<) > $@
    @$(DEPEND.d) $< >> $@

%.d:%.cp
    @printf $(dir $<) > $@
    @$(DEPEND.d) $< >> $@

%.d:%.cxx
    @printf $(dir $<) > $@
    @$(DEPEND.d) $< >> $@

%.d:%.m
    @printf $(dir $<) > $@
    @$(DEPEND.d) $< >> $@
```

Comment: The lines actually *do* make sense! The dependencies without them won't treat files in subdirectories correctly. The problem is the used `echo` (probably the one built into the shell used by `make` in your setup): it doesn't understand the `-n` option which should suppress the newline at the end of `echo`'s output.

Comment: yes, I think so. obviously, you wouldn't use the `-n` option but leave out any newline from the format. However, I don't think `printf` is a standard POSIX shell command which is probably the reason `echo` is used (although I'm not sure if the `-n` option is standard; I don’t think it is).

Comment: @DietmarKühl, The [OS X Manual page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/echo.1.html) says "*Applications aiming for maximum portability are strongly encouraged to use printf(1) to suppress the newline character.*". Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

The Makefile [exerpt] you showed doesn't show how `main.d` is created but it seems that it is included by the actual `Makefile`. It is probably meant to contain the dependencies of `main.cpp` but the `-n ./' is clearly not valid`make` syntax. Try removing the file for now and if it gets regenerated you need to find how it is generated and fix this. To see how it is generated again remove the file and use

```
make -p 2>&1 | tee mkerr
```

Once this finishes, `mkerr` contains the output of the `make` command, including the rules it used. Somewhere in there is a rule how to build `.d` files. With a bit of luck, removing the file sorts the problem...

Based on the code posted to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/fqXxDesJ) the problem is the rule of how the `%.d` files are created:

```
%.d: %.cpp
    @echo -n $(dir $<) > $@
    @$(DEPEND.d) $< << $@
```

The problem is that the `echo` which was found doesn't understand the `-n` option which is meant to avoid any newline. The first line of the rule should add a directory prefix for the file. The esieast fix is to find a better `echo` which understands the `-n` option. Although, you might need to use a different shell because `echo` tends to be a shell built-in! In that case you might be best off use a full path on the `echo` to a version which doesn't misbehave.

Comment: I've tried removing the `.d` file and run `make` again and it still does create it again. For the complete file look [here](http://pastebin.com/fqXxDesJ).

Comment: @Jeffrey: Did you run with the `-p` option to see the complete set of rules?

Comment: I've just tried running `make -p` and it prints the makefile. What is it trying to do with `-n ./`? What does the `-n` flag means? (I [tried](http://www.google.it/#hl=it&gs_nf=3&qe=LW4gZmxhZyBtYWtlZmlsZQ&qesig=uTjr2lI3792UCBsMoSjm4w&pkc=AFgZ2tmFXf6nSo26tlvpJYJnXI9bs3B1jRth0p83G1N91Cq_0m0Wb7Aib28tARcz3WPTC0w01iJutlEyqHChVAaCnRy786QRtQ&pq=gcc%20flags&cp=16&gs_id=5g&xhr=t&q=-n+flag+makefile&pf=p&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&oq=-n+flag+makefile&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=70759a6a8974c64e&bpcl=38897761&biw=1279&bih=680) and [tried](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/comopts.html) googling it)

Comment: @Jeffrey: The `-n` is meant to suppress the newline at the end of the `echo` output. However, some `echo` is used which doesn't understand the `-n` option correctly and prints it instead, followed the other arguments and a newline.